# Run MongoDB as service on Debian/Linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, debian

I want to start MongoDB as a service on Debian/Linux. But i did not found any helpful material after a lot of Googling. So any one can guide me, how i can achieve it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14.04/

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: This can only help to install MongoDB on Linux. In my case MongoDB is installed successfully. I want run MongoDB as a service on Debian/Linux.

Comment: sudo service mongod start
?

Comment: By using that command we have to start every time we started the server. But i want to start it as a service so that we don't need to start it manually every times

Comment: Is it not enabled to start when your system boot? Maybe check /etc/init/mongod.conf file? Does it have start on ? Remove that file